# Using the results linq query in another linq query

Tags: c#, linq

Good day!

Tell me whether it is possible to use the result of a Linq  query in another Linq query? 
For example:

```
    List<Member> memberList = db.Members.Where(m=>m.Year == 20013).ToList();
var result = (from members in memberList
             from documents in Archive.Where(d=>d.MemberId = members.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new ArchiveRecord
             {
                member = members,
                documentId = documentsId
             }).ToList();
```

At the same time the implementation of the second request falls with the error (There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first).

Please tell me where I made mistakes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to make nested linq query but i have solution for you. 
Try this:

```
List<Member> memberList = db.Members.Where(m => m.Year == 20013).ToList();
var membersIds = memberList.Select(m => m.Id);
var result = (from documents in Archive.Where(d => membersIds.Contains(d.MemberId)).DefultIfEmpty()
             select new ArchiveRecord
             {
                 member = members,
                 documentId = documentsId
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: I think you could use a IEnumerable instead of List and remove the ToList() of the first query to not execute the first request

Comment: @Béranger True, but note that it's probably an `IQueryable` since this looks like EF.

Comment: @juharr Yes, and IQueryable implements IEnumerable so there is no problem with it :) But we can use an IQueryable too.

Comment: Thank you it works!!
But still interesting what was caused my error

Answer (score 0):

Enable Multiple Active Result Sets ("MultipleActiveResultSets=True") in your connection string:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work (Single query):

```
var memberList = db.Members.Where(m=>m.Year == 20013);
var result = (from members in memberList
         from documents in Archive.Where(d=>d.MemberId = members.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new ArchiveRecord
         {
            member = members,
            documentId = documentsId
         }).ToList();
```

This definitely should work (Single query):

```
var result = (from members in db.Members
         from documents in Archive.Where(d=>d.MemberId = members.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
         where members.year == 20013
         select new ArchiveRecord
         {
            member = members,
            documentId = documentsId
         }).ToList();
```

and this (Two queries):

```
var membersIds = db.Members
  .Where(m => m.Year == 20013)
  .Select(m => m.Id)
  .ToList();

var result = (from documents in Archive.Where(d => membersIds.Contains(d.MemberId)).DefultIfEmpty()
             select new ArchiveRecord
             {
                 member = members,
                 documentId = documentsId
              }).ToList();
```

and this assuming you have created a navigation property on members to archive,  and it is a 1-many relationship (Single query):

```
var result=db.Archives
  .Where(a=>a.Member.Year==20013)
  .Select(a=> new ArchiveRecord {
    member=a.Member,
    documentId=a.documentsId
  }).ToList();
```